# Adding all elements from list where the value divisible by 5

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I am trying to use tail recursion but I am stuck. Please help

```
(define (sum-divis-five lst)
    (helper-function lst 0))

(define (helper-function lst answer)
    (cond[(empty? lst) answer]
         [else (if (= 0 (remainder (car lst) 5))
                   ????)
                   (helper-function (cdr lst) answer)]))
```

Comment: Start with writing a function that tail-recursively adds all numbers in a  list and the answer will appear to you.

Answer (score 1):

**Filling in**

```
(define (sum-divis-five lst)
    (helper-function lst 0))

(define (helper-function lst answer)
    (cond ((empty? lst) answer)
          ((= 0 (remainder (car lst) 5)) (helper-function (cdr lst) (+ (car lst) answer)))
          (else (helper-function (cdr lst) answer))))
```

**With `letrec`**

One can do it using `letrec` inside the function, too

```
(define (sum-divis-five L)
  (letrec ((i-sum-divis-five (lambda (L acc)
                               (cond ((empty? L) acc)
                                     ((= 0 (remainder (car L) 5))
                                      (i-sum-divis-five (cdr L)
                                                        (+ (car L) acc)))
                                     (else (i-sum-divis-five (cdr L) acc))))))
    (i-sum-divis-five L 0)))
```

**More general**

Or generalized:

```
(define (sum-divisibles L n)
  (letrec ((i-sum-divs (lambda (L n acc)
                         (cond ((empty? L) acc)
                               ((= 0 (remainder (car L) n))
                                (i-sum-divs (cdr L) n (+ (car L) acc)))
                               (else (i-sum-divs (cdr L) n acc))))))
    (i-sum-divs L n 0)))
```

With:

```
(sum-divisibles '(1 2 3 4 5 10 15 3) 5)
;; 30
```

**With special case `5`**

```
(define (sum-divis-five L)
  (sum-divisibles L 5))

(sum-divis-five '(1 2 3 4 5 10 15 3))
;; 30
```

Answer (score 0):

If you name your variables, you will get a much better overview of what you are dealing with.
Try also to divide the problem into smaller problems.

**Approach**
You want to filter out all the numbers that are not divisible by 5, then sum all the numbers in the filtered list.

**Example**

Input: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 10 12 15 3 5

Filter: 5 10 15 5

Sum: 35

**Code (auxiliary)**

```
(define (is-divisible-by? dividend divisor)
  (zero? (remainder dividend divisor)))

(define (is-divisible-by-5? dividend)
  (is-divisible-by? 5))
```

**Code (non-tail-recursive)**

```
(define (filter predicate list)
  (if (empty? list)
      '()
      (let ([element (car list)]
            [rest (cdr list)])
        (if (predicate element)
            (cons element (filter predicate rest))
            (filter predicate rest)))))

(define (sum list)
  (if (empty? list)
      0
      (let ([element (car list)]
            [rest (cdr list)])
        (+ element (sum rest)))))
```

**Code (tail-recursive)**

```
(define (filter predicate list result)
  (if (empty? list)
      result
      (let ([element (car list)]
            [rest (cdr list)])
        (if (predicate element)
            (filter predicate rest (cons element result))
            (filter predicate rest result)))))

(define (sum list result)
  (if (empty? list)
      result
      (let ([element (car list)]
            [rest (cdr list)])
        (sum rest (+ element result)))))
```

**Calling**

```
(define (solution list)
  (sum (filter is-divisible-by-5? list '()) 0))
```